# Using VB trying to calculate the checksum after input in binary

Tags: vb6

I can't figure out how to calculate the checksum after input in text1 for the data, input text1 for the divisor in binary bytes. I tried checksum.text = Text1.Text Xor Text2.Text but its not working, i searched already in internet but its only apply for C++ and java, is it possible in VB?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `XOR` on a string. You must do it on 2 numbers, not a string.

Try:

```
checksum.text = CStr(Clng(Text1.Text) Xor CLng(Text2.Text))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: This is my code                                                  Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Len(Text1.Text) & (Text2.Text) = 0 Or Text1.Text &  (Text2.Text) Like "*[!0-1]*" Then
        Text3 = "Wrong Input, Please Correct it!!"
    Else
        checksum.Text = CStr(CLng(Text1.Text) Xor CLng(Text2.Text))
        Trans(2).Text = (Text1.Text) + (checksum.Text)
        Text3 = "Congratulation CRC is generated"
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

@George

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    If Len(Text1.Text) & (Text2.Text) = 0 Or Text1.Text & Text2.Text) Like "[!0-1]" Then
        Text3 = "Wrong Input, Please Correct it!!"
    Else
        checksum.Text = CStr(CLng(Text1.Text) Xor CLng(Text2.Text))
        Trans(2).Text = (Text1.Text) + (checksum.Text) 
        Text3 = "Congratulation CRC is generated"
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Len(Text1.Text) & (Text2.Text) = 0` is wrong. Should be `Len(Text1.Text) & Len(Text2.Text) = 0`. I think the & should be OR, not AND. It won't error out, but it wont change any data because number XOR 0 = number

Comment: Unless Ricky-2135 means to concatenate Text1.Text and Text2.Text `&` should be `And`.

Comment: `Text1.Text & Text2.Text) Like "[!0-1]"` is wrong. Should be `Text1.Text Like "[!0-1]" And Text2.Text Like "[!0-1]"` But then again, what are you trying to do with the `Like`? The pattern `[!0-1]` is most likely incorrect, because all you do is check if the text is NOT a 0 or 1 but only for a single character strings. Any non-single character string will validate this as false, thus falling into `Else` amd ruining your calculation

Comment: @Jac I see what you mean, its a very bad way to code. Makes the code that much harder to read.